# How to bind property using a custom binding in FromForm situation in .Net Core Api Server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

here is my code:

**Classes**:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ChallengeDetailsDto : ChallengeDto
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PagesConverter))]
    public PageDto[] Pages { get; set; } = new PageDto[] { };
}



[Serializable]
public class CaseDto : ChallengeDto
{
    public CaseDto()
    {
        Discriminator = CaseDtoDiscriminator;
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync([FromForm]CaseDetailsDto dto)
    {
```

}

**Custom Converter**

```
internal class ChallengeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(ChallengeDto))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ChallengeDto challengeDto = null;

        var jsonChallange = JObject.Load(reader);
        var discriminator = jsonChallange.Properties().First(p => p.Name == "discriminator").Value.ToString();

        if (discriminator == ChallengeDto.CaseDtoDiscriminator)
        {
            challengeDto = (CaseDto)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonChallange.ToString(), typeof(CaseDto));
        }
        /*...*/

        return challengeDto;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var challenge = value as ChallengeDto;
        if (challenge.Discriminator == ChallengeDto.CaseDtoDiscriminator)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, (CaseDto)challenge);
        }
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

**Error**:

> Could not create an instance of type
>   'Controllers.Challenges.Dtos.PageDto'. Model bound complex types must
>   not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless
>   constructor.

If I use [FromBody], every thing works fine. From what I can understand, using [FromForm] the binding does not use Json.

What is the best way to bind Form Values to the property in this case?

Comment: `FromForm` request objects are not serialized, so your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt, I updated my question replacing Serialize by Binding